# How to capture and send packets via Macbook

Tags: wireshark, scapy, packet-sniffers, spoofing, packet-injection

I want to capture and send some packets to the access point for testing purposes. I have the packet captures made via wireshark but I do not know how to proceed to be able to send these packets from my macbook.

I tried things like scapy, colasoft etc, but they do not seem to work as they require an external wifi adapter to be able to relay these packets outwards.

Two main questions:

1. Is it possible to send custom packets from macbook to a required access point. (Without using external network adapter).
2. If yes, what are some tooling/Scripting options that I can look at ? Any recommendations?

I am networking novice so please pardon me if the question is trivial. Thank you!

Comment: Scapy can totally send packets from OSX, what's the issue there? I don't know about colasoft

Comment: Hmm. The packet that I send never reaches the access point. I am basically doing 

`packet = Dot11(
    addr1="MAC Of Access Point",
    addr2="MaC of my laptop",
    addr3="BSSID Of AP") / Dot11AssoReq(
        cap=0x1100, listen_interval=0x00a) / Dot11Elt(
            ID='SSID',len=10, info="OpenGK")`


Note: I have a WLAN called OpenGK created and being broadcasted on AP. When I do sendp(packet, iface="en1") , then it says that the packet is sent, but I cant see it on the AP

Comment: You might need to pass `monitor=True` to `sendp` but in any case, you probably want to check that your wifi adapter supports 802.11 injection (very few do)...

Comment: This brings me back to my original question. Do we need an external Wifi adapter to do this for us ? or is it possible to use Macbooks internal Wifi card/whatever we call it to do this for us ?

Answer (score 0):

Your builtin Wifi adapter likely does not support Wifi injection.

You can check this by googling the Wifi chip that is within your computer (there are various methods to get that info depending on your OS) whether it supports Wifi injection or not.

So yeah, you'll likely need an external card (check the specs before buying it)